# strange behavior with attribute in class in python 2.7.5

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

I'm new in class creating in python.
But I have got a strange behavior on version 2.7.**5**. There are no problems on 2.7.8 or 2.7.1 or 3, only on 2.7.**5**

I got this error when had tried to use my class

```
# ./script_testing.py 
Linux
('CentOS Linux', '7.1.1503', 'Core')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script_testing.py", line 1204, in <module>
    print(x.DIST)
AttributeError: WhatsName instance has no attribute 'DIST'
```

My code:

```
import platform

class WhatsName():
    """Distributive version checking and soft installing"""
    def __init__(self):

        self.PLAT=platform.system()
        self.DISTRIB=platform.linux_distribution()

        if self.PLAT=='Linux' or self.PLAT=='Linux2':
            if self.DISTRIB[0]=='debian':
                self.DIST='Debian'
            elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='Ubuntu':
                self.DIST='Ubuntu'
            elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='CentOS':
                self.DIST='Centos'
            elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='Fedora':
                self.DIST='Fedora'
            elif 'SUSE' in self.DISTRIB[0]:
                self.DIST='Suse'
            elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='Slackware':
                self.DIST='Slackware'
            else:
                pass
        elif self.PLAT=='FreeBSD':
            self.DIST='FreeBSD'
        elif PLAT=='Windows':
            self.DIST='Windows'
        elif PLAT=='Darwin':
            self.DIST='MacOS'
        else:
            self.DIST='Unknown'

    def CheckSystem(self):
        pass

    def InstallSoft(self,x,y):
        pass


x=WhatsName()
print(x.PLAT)
print(x.DISTRIB)
print(x.DIST)     <== This string generates the error
```

So, I don't understand why  DIST isn't an attribute of class WhatsName.
And why it happens only on version 2.7.5

On other versions I get the normal result:

```
"script_testing.py" 1233L, 26872C записано
:!python2.7 script_testing.py
Linux
('debian', '7.1', '')
Debian
```

Comment: Look closely *at the traceback*. That's not a traceback produced by the code you show.

Comment: Your traceback has the line `print(WhatsName.DIST)`. The code you posted uses `print(x.DIST)`. The *class* has no such attribute, only the *instance* does.

Comment: Pardon me, but I don't clearly understand  where is the mistake in my code. Why print(x.PLAT) and print(x.DISTRIB) are working well? What's the difference? And why this code works well with any other version except 2.7.5?

Comment: Yes, I have had a mistake in my error output. I have edited theme with properly error code.

Comment: May I suggest `sys.platform.lower().startswith("linux")` and similar check for distribution. I have no clue why your `CentOS` is reported as `CentOS Linux`by a specific version of python. I recommend going with string prefix.

Comment: yes, I have found the problem. Centos 7 shows as 'CentOS Linux'  and I had to rewrite condition from <elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='CentOS':> to <elif 'CentOS' in self.DISTRIB[0]:>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of your `if` statements match the first value of `self.DISTRIB`:

```
('CentOS Linux', '7.1.1503', 'Core')
```

The string is `'CentOS Linux'`, but you don't test for that string, so `self.DIST` is never set.

You only test for the string `'CentOS'`:

```
elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='CentOS':
    self.DIST='Centos'
```

This line never matches, nor do the other tests in this `if...elif...` statement. Since you don't have an `else` here to set `self.DIST` you get an attribute error at the end.

You could just fix that line:

```
elif self.DISTRIB[0]=='CentOS Linux':
    self.DIST='Centos'
```

I'd also set `self.DIST = 'Unknown'` *at the start*, so you have a default value, then have your set of `if` branches determine a more precise value.